# checking if cell value exists in two other sheets

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am trying to track IDs within several different sheets and I want to be able to give a True value for one criteria and false for another. Here is my pseudo code for what I am trying to accomplish.

```
IF sheet1.A1.value EXISTS AND DOES NOT EXIST IN sheet2.A:A OR sheet3.A:A
THEN RETURN "true"
ELSE RETURN "false"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this with just an excel formula like this:

```
=IF(AND(len('Sheet1'!A1)>0 , ISERROR(MATCH('Sheet1'!A1,'Sheet2'!A:A,0)), ISERROR(MATCH('Sheet1'!A1,'Sheet3'!A:A,0))) , "True", "False")
```

This Reads:

- If the following three condiitons are met, then True, otherwise False
- Condition 1: Sheet1's Cell A1 exists

  - Check if the length of any value in it is greater than 0
- Condition 2: Sheet1's Cell A1 not in Sheet 2's column A

  - Run a match formula to check this
  - If the match returns an error, then it was not found
- Condition 3

  - Run a match formula to check this
  - If the match returns an error, then it was not found

Comment: I ended up using several excel formulas to accomplish this, I couldn't figure out making one complex one. I will take a look tomorrow and see if I can implement your example, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim SearchString As String

    SearchString = "Blah"

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(1), SearchString) > 0 And _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1), SearchString) = 0 And _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet3").Columns(1), SearchString) = 0 Then
        '~~> Display relevant message
    Else
        '~~> Display relevant message
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I would try to do the VBA but for what I am doing I think excel formulas will work better. I am copying in new data each time I have to do this and like the excel formulas because they automatically update instead of having to run a macro each time